# VB.net - Syntax error in ms access SQL update query

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have prepared my project in vb.net with access database, but I am getting an error like "syntax error in update statement"

I have used following code:

```
Dim cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim cm As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\NAV Vikram\DATABASE NAVPREET.mdb"
cn.Open()
cm.Connection = cn
cm.CommandText = "UPDATE DATAENTRY2  set [DIAGNOSIS]='" & TextBox13.Text & "',WHERE[opdno]='" & TextBox1.Text & "' "
cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

omit `,` before `WHERE` and add space after it. Change:

```
cm.CommandText = "UPDATE DATAENTRY2  set [DIAGNOSIS]='" & TextBox13.Text & "',WHERE[opdno]='" & TextBox1.Text & "' "
```

to:

```
cm.CommandText = "UPDATE DATAENTRY2  set [DIAGNOSIS]='" & TextBox13.Text & "' WHERE [opdno]='" & TextBox1.Text & "' "
```

Also **Use SQL parameters**. (Not very keen to vb to show you example)

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error in your query. Please remove comma (`,`) you have used before where clause from query, as it is used to separate two different column

```
Dim cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim cm As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\NAV Vikram\DATABASE NAVPREET.mdb"
cn.Open()
cm.Connection = cn
cm.CommandText = "UPDATE DATAENTRY2  set [DIAGNOSIS]='" & TextBox13.Text & "' WHERE[opdno]='" & TextBox1.Text & "' "
cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
```